# React Webcam set Timeout

Tags: reactjs, webcam, webcam-capture

In React Webcam is there a way to detect when the webcam is on? The webcam can take some time to turn on and display the image. The times seem to vary between 1 second and 5 seconds maybe it depends on how fast the computer and webcam are. If user clicks on capture button before webcam is ready the image string is not saved. I have tried disabling the capture button then setTimeout() at 5 seconds then the button will be enabled, but it is not accurate. Is there a different approach I could take? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
const videoConstraints = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  facingMode: "user"
};

const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);

  const capture = React.useCallback(
    () => {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    },
    [webcamRef]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={720}
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        width={1280}
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
      />
      <button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have a problem with using onUserMedia. I want to add a loading spinner while the webcam is turning on. It seems as though I have to use a second Webcam Component in my ternary operator to use onUserMedia. It causes the webcam to turn on and off four times. Is there another way I could add a loading spinner without using two Webcam components? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
handleUserMedia = () => {
        this.setState({ showLoader: false });
    };

this.state.showLoader ? (
                 <div>
                     <Loader />
                     <p>Starting Camera...</p>
                     <div className="loading-webcam">
                          <Webcam onUserMedia={this.handleUserMedia} />
                     </div>
                 </div>
            ) : (
                 <>
                    <Webcam
                           audio={false}
                           height={365}
                           ref={this.setRef}
                     />
                  </>
             )}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the React-Webcam repo documentations. Webcam component has an onUserMedia property, it uses a callback from there I set loading to false.

https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam/issues/74

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

class App extends Component {
  handleUserMedia = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Webcam
        ref={e => this.webcam = e}
        onUserMedia={this.handleUserMedia}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: absolutely, I was wriiten the answer about using the `onUserMedia` callback, it seems you have found the solution by yourself

Comment: @OlivierBoissé wondering if you could take a look at my updated question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in case you didn't find a solution, you can see my answer above

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `style` or `className` attribute to hide the video element while loading the camera

```
render() {
  const display = this.state.loading ? 'none' : 'block';

  return (
    <>
      {this.state.loading && <Loader/>}
      <Webcam
        onUserMedia={this.handleUserMedia}
        style={{display}}
      />
    </>
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This works for me.